# How to handle special characters in Java?

Tags: java

I want to save a comment which is given by the user in DB as a CLOB. It's working fine. Later I got issue with special characters. If a user copy pastes the comment from a WordPad and it contains **"single quote"** or some special characters(they are bit different from usual) they are converting into **reversed question mark** or some **square box**. I tried to handle them by using below code. [image]

```
values[4] = new String(values[4].getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

But still I'm getting square boxes. After debugging the issue what I realized is, it is not able to handle a **space**. Please see the attached image

**Note:** the comment length is 122 and it failed to handle only one space. I don't know what's wrong with that space.

Comment: Maybe the ISO Latin 1 encoding you infer is not actually the original encoding?

Comment: The first thing you should do is check whether the problem is saving to the database, or getting the value from the user in the first place. The code you've given is almost certainly *not* what you want to do.

Comment: actually I'm getting the issue after using the above mentioned piece of code. one the comment string passing through that line it is converting **iso** to **utf**. So whatever it is not able to handle it is showing like boxes as I show in the image

Comment: Strings, if read correctly in Java, is already in Unicode. If you saved it directly to a CLOB column with a correct JDBC implementation then you would never have encoding problems. The code you gave was trying to reinterpret ISO-8859-1 as UTF8 which will never work apart from for lower 128 ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in java the encoding matters only when

1. doing some sort of (file-)IO or
2. converting characters to bytes

Java's `String`-objects are always encoded as UTF-16, so assuming that `values` is a `String[]` your code is doing the following:

1. Take the String `values[4]` as a set of characters.
2. Transform each character to one byte using ISO8859-1-encoding
3. Use UTF8-encoding to convert these bytes to characters.

e.g. the `£`-character will be converted to the byte-value `A3` but that single byte can not be converted back using UTF-8 since it could only be part of a 2-byte-sequence.

To sum it up: that codeline is completely broken, while using `String`-objects there is no need to think about any kind of encoding. Where you have to take care of codepage issues is while converting to bytes, be it during I/O to a file or network-Stream or when converting to byte-arrays for encryption.